# File 'main.ts' not found

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the correct solution for this error?

```sh
PS C:\Users\****\Like-Component> tsc main.ts
error TS6053: File 'main.ts' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation


Found 1 error.
```

Comment: If you type `DIR` in this directory, what do you have ?

Comment: @Harsha Please try with my answer and let me know if it's working.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I tryped `DIR` and it returned `command not found: DIR`

Comment: @EkanemEno `DIR` is the command used to list the files in the current directory on Windows. If you are on linux or mac, the equivalent is `ls`

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this error is already explained in the error message. Basically when you add `rootDir` address already in `tsconfig.json` file. Your `tsc` command will follow it and start looking for `.ts` files in the folder inside the address you mentioned in `rootDir`.

> just run `tsc` instead of `tsc main.ts`

your `tsc` will automatically go inside the `rootDir` and look for available ts files. Simple!

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es6",
  "module": "CommonJS",
  "outDir": "./public",
  "rootDir": "./src",
  "strict": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
 },

"include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to src folder
Create a new file named **main.ts** 
Paste following code in the file.

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Save the file
Restart project
This will work now

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But it did not work in my case.

Comment: Watch my new edit. I think this will work.